# Microsoft CNTK reinforced learning C++ examples

Tags: c++, neural-network, reinforcement-learning, cntk

I'm currently trying to write an AI in C++ that plays bomberman and I want to implement it as a neural network (reinforcement learning) with CNTK. The toolkit has a lot of tutorials and examples, even one for reinforcement learning, but it is written in python, which I don't know.

https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/v2.0.rc3/Tutorials/CNTK_203_Reinforcement_Learning_Basics.ipynb

Are there any practical C++ examples or tutorials teaching reinforcement learning with CNTK?

My first most issue is how to create a model with the CNTK C++ api.

Answer (score 0):

To create a model with the C++ API, take a look at [these C++ examples](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/tree/v2.1/Tests/EndToEndTests/CNTKv2Library/EndToEndTests).

For reinforcement learning, you need an environment in which you can act and get rewards. The only environment I know out there in C++ is the [Arcade Learning Environment](https://github.com/mgbellemare/Arcade-Learning-Environment). There are many environments available in Python such as [openai's gym](https://gym.openai.com/).

Unfortunately, CNTK doesn't have any examples of RL in C++. If you follow the Python examples however and translate things in C++, there's no reason why you cannot make it work.